# How to properly bind values to 'from' and 'to', inside a NumberAnimation?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to create a horizontal scrolling text animation (enter at the right side, go through the screen, exit at the left side, repeat).

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        id: scrollLine
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        Text {
            id: scrollText
            color: "white"
            text: "This is a test"
            font.pixelSize: parent.height * 0.5
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            x: scrollLine.width
            NumberAnimation on x {
                id: scrollAnimation
                from: scrollLine.width; to: -scrollText.width
                duration: 5000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that my text acts weird. Appears left side, scrolls left with two characters, repeat... Something is wrong at the binding
`from: scrollLine.width; to: -scrollText.width`,
but I have no idea what.

Comment: set `font.pixelSize` to a fixed size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is weird! :)

The first thing I can see is that this

```
x: scrollLine.width
```

does nothing. The `NumberAnimation` runs immediately, causing the `x` value of the `Text` to be set, so we can remove that code to make it easier to find the problem.

The next thing to do is to print out the `width`s of the items:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: scrollLine
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        onHeightChanged: print("rectangle height", height)

        Text {
            id: scrollText
            color: "white"
            text: "This is a test"
            font.pixelSize: parent.height * 0.5
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            onWidthChanged: print("text width", width)

            NumberAnimation on x {
                id: scrollAnimation
                from: scrollLine.width
                to: -scrollText.width
                duration: 5000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That gives us:

```
qml: text width 72.078125
qml: rectangle height 160
qml: text width 443.734375
```

Ok, it's weird that the text size changes width, but... it indirectly depends on the size of the window, right? We set its `font.pixelSize` to `parent.height * 0.5`. It just so happens that the window size is determined after the `Text` gets its initial size. However, being a declarative language, you'd think this should work.

Let's check the `from` and `to` values of the animation:

```
onFromChanged: print("from", from)
onToChanged: print("to", to)
```

Now we get:

```
qml: from 0
qml: to 0
qml: text width 72.078125
qml: to -72.078125
qml: from 160
qml: rectangle height 160
qml: text width 443.734375
qml: to -443.734375
```

They are initially incorrect, sure, but they do eventually become correct. This smells like a bug. Let's double check by printing out the `x` position of the `Text`:

```
qml: x -0.576625
...
qml: x -71.4654609375
```

That's not right. It seems like a bug. I thought it was, too, but then I checked the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html#from-prop):

> If the NumberAnimation is defined within a Transition or Behavior, this value defaults to the value defined in the starting state of the Transition, or the current value of the property at the moment the Behavior is triggered.

You're not using a `Behavior`, although the syntax looks very similar. A bit more searching reveals the [documentation for the `on` keyword](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#using-predefined-targets-and-properties):

> The animation starts as soon as the rectangle is loaded, and will automatically be applied to its x and y values.

So, it's not a bug. You'll have to give the animation sensible `from` and `to` values somehow. One solution is to hard-code the values:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    width: 250
    height: 250
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: scrollLine
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"

        Text {
            id: scrollText
            color: "white"
            text: "This is a test"
            font.pixelSize: parent.height * 0.5
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            NumberAnimation on x {
                id: scrollAnimation
                from: root.width
                to: -1000
                duration: 5000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The best solution would probably be not to rely on the window's `height` for the font size, though. The default font size chosen by Qt is legible on all platforms that provide sensible DPI information, so you would be better off multiplying that by some factor:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    width: 250
    height: 250
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: scrollLine
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"

        FontMetrics {
            id: fontMetrics
        }

        Text {
            id: scrollText
            color: "white"
            text: "This is a test"
            font.pixelSize: fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 8
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            NumberAnimation on x {
                id: scrollAnimation
                from: root.width
                to: -1000
                duration: 5000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code you specified the `width` and the `height` of the `root` element. With this, and the fixed font size, my code works as expected too. Unfortunately I cannot give these properties in my case, because I need to run my app on different kind of monitors, with different screen resolutions. I need this application up and running now, so I will use the variant with the hardcoded `from` and `to` values. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Right, I probably shouldn't have assumed that the size of the window would be known... interesting problem, though. Note that even if you use a `NumberAnimation` without the `on` keyword (instead specifying `target` and `property`), it still takes the initial values. I'd say that's a bug.

Comment: BUUUUUGG!! (love to shout it out loud)

Answer (score 0):

You code works as expected with a little modification. Instead of using `font.pixelSize: parent.height*0.5`, I used a fixed size point. Try this

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        id: scrollLine
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        Text {
            id: scrollText
            color: "white"
            text: "This is a test"
            font.pixelSize: 150; //////// Changed this
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            x: scrollLine.width
            NumberAnimation on x {
                id: scrollAnimation
                from: scrollText.width; to: -scrollText.width
                duration: 5000
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With your modification the text exits as expected, but appears at left side after (I am expecting it right). I suspect, that the `scrollLine.width` is `0`, but I don't know why.. Thank you for your time!

Comment: updated the answer. changed `from` and `to`. Text always starts at the right now.